# Суммирование столбцов двумерного массива

Tags: c++, linux, массивы

Нужна помощь в разработке программы приведения двумерного массива к одномерному (элементы результирующего одномерного массива представляет собой суммы элементов соответствующих им столбцов исходного массива).

Массив заполняется случайным образом. Размер массива задаётся пользователем в терминале при запуске программы. Программа должна состоять как минимум из двух исходных файлов *.cpp.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то Вам нужно не *преобразование*, а *получение* массива, содержащего сумму столбцов матрицы.

Если так, то в чем проблема?

Делаете массив размерностью в число столбцов матрицы. Для каждого столбца суммируете его элементы (т.е. во внутреннем цикле двигаетесь по строкам) и заносите ее в очередной элемент одномерного массива-результата.

Voila

Comment: О боже, "как минимум из двух файлов", шедевр. Положите один пустой файл или с одним `#define` или `#include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Излагаю своё видение решения задачи.

```
main.cpp
UserInterfaceManager uima;
//std::vector<double> initialData;//далее буду оперировать более привычным QVector
int rows(0), columns(0);
QVector<double> initialData;//initial matrix
uima.takeMatrix(initialData, rows, columns);
QVector<double> result = MatrixProcessor::compress(initialData, rows, columns);
uima.showVector(result);

class UserInterfaceManager
UserInterfaceManager::takeMatrix(QVector<double> &retVal, int &rows, int &columns)
{
//здесь запрашиваем через консоль число строк, столбцов, циклом запрашиваем значения, пишем построчно(или постолбцово) в retVal
}

class MatrixProcesor
QVector<double> MatrixProcesor::compress(const QVector<double> &, int rows, int columns);
```